# $(document).height returns incorrect height the first time, correct the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put a pop up screen, and I want to darken the background when pop up opens.
This is the Javascript.

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
        $("#popUp").css("display" , "block");
        var divId = $(this).attr("id");
        $.get('portfolio/portfolio.xml', function(file){
            $(file).find('item').filter(function() {return $(this).attr("id") == divId;}).each(function(){
                var $item = $(this);
                var name = $item.find("name");
                var description = $item.find('description'); 
                $("#popUpName").html(name.text()) ;
                $("#popUpDescription").html(description.text());
                var im; var n=0;
                $item.find('image').each(function() {
                    var i = "<img src='" + $(this).text() + "'></img>";
                    i += "<div>" + $(this).attr("description") + "</div>";
                    $("#popUpImage").append(i);
                });
                setPopUpHeight();
                $(document).scrollTop(0);
            });
        }); 
    });

    function setPopUpHeight() {
            //alert($(document).height());
            $("#popUp").height($(document).height());
            alert($("#popUp").height());
    }
```

For example: In one case the first time the value is 3701, the second time it's 4196.

Edit: $(document).height, changed from $(window).height.
Edit: I should add that if uncomment the first alert, the second time document.height returns the right value.

Comment: Mybe all images are not fully loaded when you call setPopUpHeight()

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$(document).height()` with `$(window).height()`.

Also moved the `SetPopUpHeight()` and `scrollTop()` calls which need not be called once per `'item'`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
        $("#popUp").css("display" , "block");
        var divId = $(this).attr("id");
        $.get('portfolio/portfolio.xml', function(file){
            $(file).find('item').filter(function() {return $(this).attr("id") == divId;}).each(function(){
                var $item = $(this);
                var name = $item.find("name");
                var description = $item.find('description'); 
                $("#popUpName").html(name.text()) ;
                $("#popUpDescription").html(description.text());
                var im; var n=0;
                $item.find('image').each(function() {
                    var i = "<img src='" + $(this).text() + "'></img>";
                    i += "<div>" + $(this).attr("description") + "</div>";
                    $("#popUpImage").append(i);
                });
            });
            setPopUpHeight();
            $(document).scrollTop(0);
        }); 
    });

    function setPopUpHeight() {
            //alert($(document).height());
            $("#popUp").height($(window).height());
            alert($("#popUp").height());
    }
```

Comment: You should tell what you have changed in the code to let the user know what he did wrong while writing this code.

Comment: `$(document).height()` is replaced with `$(window).height()`;

Comment: i changed too the location of "setPopUpHeight();" was called.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `$(window).height().top;` it should display correctly